# Why is pigpio library not moving my servo when the same pin number works perfectly with RPi.GPIO?

Tags: gpio, pigpio, servo

I am working on a self driving rc car project and I need a servo to steer my car. As I was getting a bit jitter with RPi.GPIO I tried pigpio library. I am using a Raspbery Pi Model B. But it won't move my servo. I am using pin 10 which is gpio 16.
My this code with rpi.GPIO is working -

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(10,gpio.OUT)
pwm = gpio.PWM(10,80)
pwm.start(0)

def SetAngle(angle):
    duty = angle / 18 + 2
    gpio.output(10, True)
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
    sleep(1)
    gpio.output(10, False)
    # pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
try:
    while True:
        angle = float(input('ENTER ANGLE PLEASE: '))
        SetAngle(angle)

except:
    SetAngle(0)
    pwm.stop()
    gpio.cleanup()
```

But this code using pigpio is not -

```
import pigpio
import math

GPIO_SERVO_PIN  = 10

MIN_ANG=-180.0 #degrees
MAX_ANG=180.0  #degrees

MIN_PW=1000 # microseconds
MAX_PW=2000 # microseconds

ANG_RANGE=MAX_ANG-MIN_ANG
PW_RANGE=MAX_PW-MIN_PW
PWAR=float(PW_RANGE)/ANG_RANGE

RAD2DEG=180.0/math.pi

def angleToPulseWidth(angle):
   """
   angle is mapped to valid pulse widths for servo
   which are determined by experiment.
   """
   assert MIN_ANG <= angle <= MAX_ANG
   return MIN_PW + ((angle - MIN_ANG) * PWAR)

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
    exit()
while True:
    angle = float(input('Please enter a angle: '))
    pw = angleToPulseWidth(angle)
    pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(GPIO_SERVO_PIN, pw)
```

I have run the following command also which let's us use the pigpio library -

`sudo pigpiod`

Comment: pigpio ONLY supports BCM pin numbers

Comment: Thank you @Milliways, it worked. I just came to know about the library today but I didn't find this information by google search.

Comment: If it works now please make an answer. This finished the question and will show others that your question has a solution and they don't try to help you for nothing.

Comment: Ok good suggestion @Ingo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PiGPIO supports only BCM pins. Looks like I have used board pins due to which my servo is not moving. I changed the pin numbering to BCM and passed the pin GPIO number 18. Do not write the pin number write the BCM number. For example - If I inserted it in pin 12 which is BCM 18 then to set servo position I'll do -

```
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(18, pw)
```

not

```
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(12, pw)
```